# In my xampp ubuntu my project directory is unrechable

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, lampp

My project directory is

> /opt/lampp/htdocs/mpa/

all directory is accessable but when I'm going to

> localhost/mpa
>   the bellow page is comming

---

**Object not found**

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

**Error 404**

localhost
Apache/2.4.4 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.3 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3

---

I've tried chmod 777 -R mpa
but it is notworking,
is there any conflict with git?
because last time when i created git repo in this directory after that this directory became unreachable

please give me solution.

Comment: - Have you a index file in your mpa/ directory, corresponding to your DirectoryIndex Apache directive ?

Comment: - Can you access to a particular file in your directory ? What is logged in apache error.log ?

Comment: yes there is index.php and I can not access to any file in my project directory.